# Excel: Use value in one worksheet to unhide rows in another worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I have a userform that enters all the information I need on, let's call it "SheetA". Now I have a bunch of hidden rows in a separate worksheet "SheetB" and would like certain ones to unhide based on criteria from SheetA.

I'm sure the answer is simple, but it's just not clicking.

Comment: Best way to learn how to do this is record a macro whilst hiding and unboxing columns, that'll get you started on the syntax you need to do the un/hiding. Then come back and update your question when you get stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is a solution that works for me, nothing special. It's a worksheet sub that will be triggered everytime a value in A1 or B1 changes. Hope it helps.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'Here you define what range in SheetA the data will be entered and the macro
'will only run if data is changed in that range.

    Dim Area As Range
    Set Area = Range("A1:B1")
    
'The "If Not Application..." checks means that IF data is changed THEN run.
    If Not Application.Intersect(Area, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then

'Here you start your criteria for the conditions under which rows should be unhidden
'I called it "TestValue1" but it could be any value.
        If Range("A1").Cells.Value = "TestValue1" And _
        Range("B1").Cells.Value = "TestValue2" Then
        
            Worksheets("SheetB").Rows("1:2").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Worksheets("SheetB").Rows("3:4").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            
        ElseIf Range("A1").Cells.Value = "TestValue1" Then
            
            Worksheets("SheetB").Rows("1:2").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        
        ElseIf Range("B1").Cells.Value = "TestValue2" Then
        
            Worksheets("SheetB").Rows("3:4").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

I also have to say that this macro is relatively sloppy if you're working with a lot of data, since it will require you to write loads of IF statements. There are definitely more efficient ways of doing this task but I haven't had the time to look at it closely enough.

Comment: This is awesome and gives me a great place to start. Some of the syntax is definitely foreign to me, so I hope you can help me plug in what I need to plug in. I realize now that there's a third sheet in the equation too. Abridged version:
- Name is entered in cell on Sheet A (One of 37 records)
- Based on what name is entered - there are only a few names available to choose from - the corresponding record should appear on the person's named sheet, Sheet B, and disappear from the "unassigned" sheet, Sheet C.

Sorry for adding an extra sheet to the equation!

Comment: To expand, and I don't know if this is the best way to go about it, I've just duplicated all records from the main list "Sheet A" into the specific individual's sheets "Sheet B" and the unassigned records sheet "Sheet C". I've hidden the records on Sheet B so they will unhide when the code runs, and conversely, they records are all visible on Sheet C *until* it pops up on another sheet, at which point it should get hidden. :)

Comment: Check the edits in my answer. I would highly recommend just looking through some other forums to see what can be done. Alternatively you could try to make a loop that runs through all the possible names and if it hits the correct one, the row that is associated with that name is unhidden in B and hidden in C. Loops are important concepts in VBA so I highly recommend having a look at it.

Comment: Thank you! I'll do some reading and get familiarized with it. Thanks for you help!!